# Extract APK supported CPU architecture

Tags: android

How can I extract the type of architecture a certain APK was built for? I have to different APKs, one for 'x86' and the other for 'armeabi-v7a'.

Comment: Look in the `libs` folder inside the APK. Within it there should be folders for each ABI that it contains native libraries for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have .so files. While importing them, you need to classify your folders. So each releated .so files should go related folder that is named.

- libs

  - arm

    *lib.so
  - x86

    *lib.so

Comment: What if there is no `lib` directory ?